# Create user with custom attribute using AdminCreateUser in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create user in AWS Cognito with adminCreateUser API with the below code

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

var params = {
      UserPoolId: "us-east-1_302HlhnaC", /* required */
      Username : "test@yopmail.com",
      ForceAliasCreation: true,
      TemporaryPassword: 'test@yopmail.com',
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: 'given_name', /* required */
          Value: 'test'
        },
        {
          Name: 'family_name', /* required */
          Value: 'kumar'
        },
        {
          Name: 'name', /* required */
          Value: 'test'
        },
        {
          Name: 'custom:dob', /* required */
          Value: '1990-07-25'
        },
        {
          Name: 'email', /* required */
          Value: 'test@yopmail.com',
        },
        {
          Name: 'email_verified', /* required */
          Value: 'true',
        }
        /* more items */
      ],

};


cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminCreateUser(params, function(error, data) {
    console.log(error,data);
    res.send("test");
});
```

It always throwing following exception :
InvalidParameterException: Attributes did not conform to the schema: custom:dob: Attribute does not exist in the schema.

Is am doing anything wrong,if yes please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You must add the custom attribute ahead of time. You can create custom attributes by visiting the User Pool and clicking the `Attributes` link.

Comment: So I'm on the IAM management console, I'm not seeing a UserPool option.

Comment: A UserPool is part of AWS Cognito. Look there. AWS IAM is a separate service which you don't seem to need.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding my case here.

In my CloudFormation, I have:

```
  Schema:
    - AttributeDataType: String
      Name: role
      DeveloperOnlyAttribute: true
      Mutable: true
      Required: false
```

In the console, it translated into:
[image]

In the application `adminCreateUser` call, I had to provide it as `dev:custom:role`:

```
  cognitoService.adminCreateUser({
    UserPoolId: config.cognitoUserPoolId,
    Username: email,
    UserAttributes: [{
      Name: 'dev:custom:role',
      Value: role,
    }]
  }).promise()
```

Figured it out by trying. Wish I knew where the docs for this are.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! There are 0 docs on this. 

Changing `'custom:dev:custom:role'` to `'dev:custom:role'` makes it work...

Comment: Yes, this is terrible documentation on their part. I wasted a good 2 hours trying to figure out why it wasn't working. Thank you for the thorough answer

Comment: My problem was also that custom attributes needed `custom:` prefix which wasn't documented, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Darcy's answer is correct. But I wanted to elaborate as that answer was focused on the AWS web console.

Also the other answer viz., prefixing "dev:" is probably an undocumented workaround (hence no documentation) and might stop working without warning.

First, the custom attributes has to be created when the Userpool is Created.

```
        CreateUserPoolRequest request = new CreateUserPoolRequest
        {
           ...

            Schema = new List<SchemaAttributeType>
            {
            new SchemaAttributeType
            {
                Name = "email",
                AttributeDataType = AttributeDataType.String,
                Required = true,
                Mutable = false
            },
            new SchemaAttributeType //custom attribute
            {
                Name = "blah",
                AttributeDataType = AttributeDataType.String,
                Mutable = false
            },

            ...
        };
```

And then when the user is created, it can be set.

```
        var request = new AdminCreateUserRequest
        {
             ...

            UserAttributes = new List<AttributeType>
            {
                new AttributeType
                {
                    Name = "email",
                    Value = "xyz@xyz.com"
                },
                new AttributeType //custom attribute
                {
                    Name = $"custom:blah",
                    Value = "value for blah"
                }
            }
        };
```

Now, just prefixing with "custom:" works.

Also note AWS continues with its tradition of having inconsistent api's by not having to prefix when creating the user pool and having the prefix when creating the user.